# Linux SPI Write then Read transaction with no Delay

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, spi

I have built a device driver for an embedded board that reads and writes over a SPI bus to an external device using the [spi_write_then_read()](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/linux-manual-4.8/spi_write_then_read.9.en.html) function. Performing writes works as expected. The SPI interface is a 4 bus (SCLK, CS, MOSI, MISO).

The image below shows a transaction where (SCK = SCLK, SDI = MOSI and MUXOUT = MISO)

[image: SDI = MOSI, MUXOUT = MISO]

Here's the kernel snippet for the read routine,

```c
static int lmx_read(struct lmx2xxx_driver *lmx2xxx, u16 reg, u16 * rbuf)                                                                                                                                           
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    u8 buf[3];                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    u8 rbbuf[2];                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    int ret;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    struct spi_device *spi = lmx2xxx->spi;                                                                                                                                                                         

    if (reg > lmx2xxx->nregs) {                                                                                                                                                                                    
        dev_err(&spi->dev, "Read Error, reg 0x%x out of range", reg);                                                                                                                                              
        return -1;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    /* send lower 7 bits, highest bit = 1 when reading */                                                                                                                                                          
    buf[0] = (uint8_t)((reg & 0x7f) | 0x80);                                                                                                                                                                       
    /* pad with dummy bytes for shifting in reading */                                                                                                                                                             
    buf[1] = 0x0;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    buf[2] = 0x0;                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    ret = spi_write_then_read(spi, &buf[0], 1, &rbbuf[0], 2);                                                                                                                                                      
    if (ret < 0) {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        dev_err(&spi->dev, "Read Error %d", ret);                                                                                                                                                                  
        return ret;                                                                                                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    *rbuf = (uint16_t)((rbbuf[0]<<8) | (rbbuf[1]));                                                                                                                                                                

    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

Looking at the signals on a scope I see that there is a delay after the 8-bit write for some amount of time (much bigger than clock period), then the SCLK comes back for 16-bit after the delay for the read portion. However when the clock comes back I don't see the MISO data because I believe I am introducing an error by not following the protocol described in their datasheet (I.e. massive delay between write and read).

If I set the write buffer to be 3 bytes (`ret = spi_write_then_read(spi, &buf[0], 3, &rbbuf[0], 2);`) I can see the data come in on the MISO line after the first byte like it is supposed to, but the function I'm using doesn't catch it, it instead performs another delay then asserts the SCLK for 2 byte length where there is of course nothing to read.

Is there another function that I can use that will perform back to back write then read without stopping the SCLK? I've tried `spi_w8r16()` but it is functionally the same as the `spi_write_then_read(spi, &buf[0], 1, &rbbuf[0], 2);` method.

In scope captures SCLK on top MISO on bottom.

Output when using, `spi_write_then_read(spi, &buf[0], 1, &rbbuf[0], 2);`.

[image]

Full output when using, `spi_write_then_read(spi, &buf[0], 3, &rbbuf[0], 2);` showing the additional 2 read cycles tagged on after a delay

[image]

The correct desired output from the device can be seen when using, `spi_write_then_read(spi, &buf[0], 3, &rbbuf[0], 2);` showing the data at the correct spot for capture but of course this data isn't saved to the `rbbuf` which is only looking at the data captured at the tailing 2 bytes after the massive delay.

[image]

Comment: I do not believe the delay is a real problem here. (The delay between reading bytes can be the issue on some hardware, but it is not the case here) What your scope pictures are missing is the CS# to be sure it's not toggled in between.  Also, any links to the hardware datasheet?

Comment: CS# remains asserted between the write and read cycles. https://www.ti.com/product/LMX2595

Comment: `spi_write_then_read()` sets up the `struct spi_message` with a list of two `struct spi_transfer`s, one for tx-only and one for rx-only. Perhaps you could instead set up a `struct spi_message` containing a list of one `struct spi_transfer` set up for bi-directional transfer, containing both tx and rx buffers of length 3. (Note that buffers need to be DMA-safe, e.g. allocated by `kmalloc`, **not** stack memory.) Then use `spi_sync()` to perform the transfer. The result should be in bytes [1] and [2] of the rx buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing might be improved by setting up the SPI message as a single bi-directional transfer as in this untested code:

```c
static int lmx_read(struct lmx2xxx_driver *lmx2xxx, u16 reg, u16 *rbuf)
{
    struct spi_device *spi = lmx2xxx->spi;
    struct spi_message message;
    struct spi_transfer x;
    u8 *buf;
    int ret;

    if (reg > lmx2xxx->nregs) {
        dev_err(&spi->dev, "Read Error, reg 0x%x out of range\n", reg);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    /*
     * Allocate DMA-safe space for tx and rx buffers, both 3 bytes long.
     * Use a single 6-byte buffer for convenience.
     *
     * Note: this buffer should not be allocated on the stack because that
     * is not DMA-safe for all architectures.
     */
    buf = kmalloc(6, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!buf) {
        dev_err(&spi->dev, "Memory allocation failure\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    /* send lower 7 bits, highest bit = 1 when reading */
    buf[0] = (uint8_t)((reg & 0x7f) | 0x80);
    /* pad with dummy bytes for shifting in reading */
    buf[1] = 0x0;
    buf[2] = 0x0;

    /* Set up SPI message with a single bi-directional transfer. */
    spi_message_init(&message);
    memset(&x, 0, sizeof(x));
    x.len = 3;
    x.tx_buf = &buf[0];
    x.rx_buf = &buf[3];
    spi_message_add_tail(&x, &message);

    /* Do the I/O. */
    ret = spi_sync(spi, &message);
    if (ret < 0) {
        dev_err(&spi->dev, "Read Error %d\n", ret);
        goto out;
    }

    /*
     * Read buffer starts at &buf[3], but first byte is the dummy byte read
     * while outputting the register number, so the read value starts at
     * &buf[4].
     */
    *rbuf = (uint16_t)((buf[4] << 8) | (buf[5]));

out:
    kfree(buf);
    return ret;
}
```